# Molecular Script usage

Tags: particles, collision

I just downloaded Molecular Script from Pyroevil. I've searched online but i can't seem to find an answer as to how do I use it or mess with its properties somesay that you just enable it but nothing really happened when I turned it on my addons window.

Comment: Moby Motion recently posted this tutorial: http://www.mobymotionblog.com/2017/01/molecular-addon-script-everything-you-need-to-know.html

Comment: Basic google search yielded this http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-docs/